# Close and reopen a PDF file

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf

I'm setting up a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which copies and opens a [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) file.

But if the same file is open it cant open the file again. (Updated version)

Is it possible to close the file and then reopen the file again?

I open the `.pdf` with:

```
start %userprofile%\desktop\xxx\xxx-Report-xxx.pdf
```

Comment: why are you opening the original file at all if you're just trying to copy it and then open the copy? if that doesn't avoid your issue and you're only working with one .pdf at a time, you can just `taskkill /f /im` your .pdf viewing application before opening the new .pdf: https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'll go ahead and throw it in an answer so you can accept and we can close the question

Comment: Carsten, I have removed your latest question edit. If you want to provide an answer, please do so in the answer area. _Should you subsequently feel that your answer, is the most suitable solution to your initial question, there's nothing to prevent you from accepting your own answer._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to open the original file prior to simply copying it, you can avoid doing so and just open the copy. Otherwise, if you are handling one .pdf at a time you can use `taskkill /f /im` to force your .pdf application to close. Another option is to copy and rename prior to opening either file, though I'm not sure why you would want to have both open at the same time:

```
@echo off

copy /y "%userprofile%\desktop\IETM Label.pdf" "IETM Label-copy.pdf"

start PDFAPP.exe "%userprofile%\desktop\IETM Label.pdf"
start PDFAPP.exe "%userprofile%\desktop\IETM Label-copy.pdf"
```